# 'make you even a coin' vs 'make you earn even a coin'

Tags: grammar, popular-refrains

There's a Korean saying that 'Making some money is not just simple or easy but really hard.'

So, I want to translate this saying in its Korean literal meaning,
but It is hard for me to choose which makes more sense.

"Digging in the ground doesn't make you even a coin."

"Digging in the ground doesn't make you earn even a coin."

I would really appreciate if you guys help me! :)

Comment: It didn't work out that way for De Beers.

Comment: There already is a common saying in English that conveys the same idea you seem to be talking about: "Money doesn't grow on trees."

Comment: @SvenYargs Doesn't 'money doesn't grow on trees' just mean that you have to expend effort to gain money, it isn't just there for the picking, while it seems the Korean one is saying 'hard work alone doesn't gain you money'.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit as to the literal translation and just what the meaning is? As I'm understanding  at present, the literal phrase is something about digging not getting you money, but the meaning is 'making money is hard'.  But I'm not quite getting the link. Is the idea that *merely* digging doesn't pay because the digging needs to be done with some purpose... ie a hole does you no good but a well or foundations would?

Answer (score 2):

Digging in the ground does not earn you a single coin.
Or
Digging in the ground doesn't earn you even a single coin.

Comment: Or a bit more idiomatically (U.S. idioms), "You can spend all day digging in the ground and not earn a red cent."